# Conjecture on the range of the mapping $T:\mathbf{x}\mapsto \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ where $\mathbf{x}\in [0,\infty)^N$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, positive-definite

For every real vector $\mathbf{z} = (z_1,\ldots,z_N)^\top$, define the function  $\textsf{sg}:\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ as
$$
{\textsf{sg}}(\mathbf{z}) =
  \begin{cases}
  \ \ \ \phantom{-} 1 \qquad\text{if $\left(\forall\,z_i\neq 0\right)$  ${\textsf{sgn}}(z_i) = 1$ }\\[10pt]
\ -1 \qquad\text{if $\left(\forall\,z_i\neq 0\right)$  ${\textsf{sgn}}(z_i) = -1$ }\\[10pt]
  \ \ \ \phantom{-} 0 \qquad\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$
where $\textsf{sgn}(\cdot)$ is the usual [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

**Conjecture:** Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an $N\times N$ positive definite matrix and denote $\mathbf{A}_i$ as its $i$-th row. Then, the range of the mapping $T:[0,\infty)^N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ defined as $T: \mathbf{x} \mapsto \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ is the Cartesian product
$$
  {\textsf{ran}}(T) = I_1 \times I_2 \times \cdots \times I_N
$$
    where, for $k=1,2,\ldots,N$, 
    $$
I_k = 
\begin{cases}
   \ [0,\infty)\qquad\ \ \ \text{if $\textsf{sg}(\mathbf{A}_k) = 1$}\\[10pt] 
   \ (-\infty,0] \qquad \text{if $\textsf{sg}(\mathbf{A}_k) = -1$}\\[10pt] 
   \ (-\infty,\infty) \quad\ \text{if $\textsf{sg}(\mathbf{A}_k) = 0$.}
\end{cases}   
$$
**Questions:**  Is this true? If not, can we give one counterexample?

**A special case for illustration:**

Consider the positive definite matrix 
$$
\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}2&-1&0\\-1&2&-1\\0&-1&2\end{bmatrix}\text{.}
$$
The mapping $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ explicitly results to the system
$$
\begin{align}
 y_1 &= 2x_1 - x_2 \\
 y_2 &= -x_1 + 2x_2 - x_3 \\
 y_3 &= -x_2 + 2x_3 \\
\end{align}\text{.}
$$
Thus, by observation, one can see that as $x_1$,$x_2$, and $x_3$ takes on values from $[0,\infty)$, the conjecture implies that the values of $y_1,y_2,y_3$ ranges on the entire $\mathbb{R}$.

One can still show other positive definite matrices. The question is, is this true for all?

Comment: $[0,\infty)^N$ is not a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^N$

Comment: With abuse of the term "linear transformation", the problem require not to be so.

Comment: @PanchalShamsundar , I have edited the word "transformation" to "mapping" which is the proper term to be used.

Comment: If the coefficients of a hyperplane is positive and you variables vary over a non-negative domain, the image is bound to be non negative.

Comment: Yes. How about the other two cases for the (non-zero) coefficients: (1) not all signs are the same, (2) all are negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\mathbf{x}\in[0,\infty)^N$. Then $T(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{Ax}\in I_1\times I_2\times \cdots\times I_N$.

Proof: Denote the $j^\text{th}$ entry in the $i^\text{th}$ row of $\mathbf{A}$ by $\mathbf{A}_{ij}$. Then the $k^\text{th}$ entry of $T(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{Ax}$ is $$T(\mathbf{x})_k=\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{A}_{ki}\mathbf{x}_i=\mathbf{A}_{k1}\mathbf{x}_1+\mathbf{A}_{k2}\mathbf{x}_2+\dots+\mathbf{A}_{N2}\mathbf{x}_2$$

It suffices to show that $T(\mathbf{x})_k\in I_k$ for all $k$.

Let $k\leq N$. If $\textsf{sg}(\mathbf{A}_k)=1$, then, by definition of signum $\mathbf{A}_{ki}>0$ for all $i\leq N$, and $I_k=[0,\infty)$. Since the domain of $T$ is $[0,\infty)^N$, each $\mathbf{x}_i\geq 0$. Thus the term $\mathbf{A}_{ki}\mathbf{x}_i\geq0$:

$$\mathbf{A}_{ki}>0\quad\text{and}\quad\mathbf{x}_i\geq0
\implies \mathbf{A}_{ki}\mathbf{x}_i\geq0$$

Since each term is $\geq 0$, the sum is $\geq 0$:

$$\forall i\leq N,\quad\mathbf{A}_{ki}\mathbf{x}_i\geq0
\implies T(\mathbf{x})_k=\sum_i \mathbf{A}_{ki}\mathbf{x}_i\geq0
\iff T(\mathbf{x})_k\in [0,\infty)=I_k$$

The argument is nearly identical if $\textsf{sg}(\mathbf{A}_k)<1$, so that $I_k=(-\infty,0]$:

$$\mathbf{A}_{ki}<0\quad\text{and}\quad\mathbf{x}_i\geq0
\implies \mathbf{A}_{ki}\mathbf{x}_i\leq0$$
$$\forall i\leq N,\quad\mathbf{A}_{ki}\mathbf{x}_i\leq0
\implies T(\mathbf{x})_k=\sum_i \mathbf{A}_{ki}\mathbf{x}_i\leq0
\iff T(\mathbf{x})_k\in (-\infty,0]=I_k$$

Otherwise, if $\textsf{sg}(\mathbf{A}_k)=0$, then $I_k=(-\infty,\infty)$, and $T(\mathbf{x})_k=\sum_i \mathbf{A}_{ki}\mathbf{x}_i \in (-\infty,\infty)$ simply because the real numbers are algebraically closed.

Comment: QED. Never thought of the reason "because the real numbers are algebraically closed"

Comment: Also note I didn't use that  $\mathbf{A}$ was positive-definite.